# ICACLS add Local Group in powershell

Tags: batch-file, icacls

Hi I'm doing some automated folder permissions across servers and I've created a group with the same name on remote machines and i'm trying to grant the group access to a folder but icacls seems to not like local groups, it can't add them to the folder...

For example it adds domain\user, domain\group, builtin\administrators fine

but when i try localmachine\localgroup is chokes... Any ideas?

I am doing this through powershell but I don't think that should be an issue.. I'd get the SID but i'm guessing it's tricky because I'm executing on the remote machine via invoke-command

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the `localmachine\` from `localmachine\localgroup`. You shouldn't need to specify the local computer name, when you're deploying the `icacls` command through PowerShell Remoting (specifically `Invoke-Command`). You might notice in the `icacls` help that it does not require the computer name as a prefix.

```
Examples:

        icacls c:\windows\* /save AclFile /T
        - Will save the ACLs for all files under c:\windows
          and its subdirectories to AclFile.

        icacls c:\windows\ /restore AclFile
        - Will restore the Acls for every file within
          AclFile that exists in c:\windows and its subdirectories.

        icacls file /grant Administrator:(D,WDAC)
        - Will grant the user Administrator Delete and Write DAC
          permissions to file.

        icacls file /grant *S-1-1-0:(D,WDAC)
        - Will grant the user defined by sid S-1-1-0 Delete and
          Write DAC permissions to file.
```

Comment: Tried that and no dice, it appears to be reading sids off the local machine instead of the remote ...

Comment: But you're deploying the script through `Invoke-Command`, right? icacls.exe should be executing on the remote computer, and have zero knowledge of your "local computer"